# Retrieve Values from database using Entityframework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-4

[image][image]I want to retrieve all rows which satisfying a condition. But when i tries only row count is correctly showing on debugging and the very first row value is repeatedly getting. following is my code

```
var data = (from jlist in entity.JobDetails
            where jlist.JobID == QJobID
            select jlist).ToList();
```

only first row value is showing in the var data. I have more than 1 items to be displayed

Comment: @GiladGreen how to add picture

Comment: How are you debugging?  Linq queries are tricky to debug since they often use deferred execution and can be wrappers over larger collections.

Comment: i have added pictures of both output and dubugging.

Comment: This indicates that the primary key of `JobDetails` isn't defined correctly.

Comment: can you show the code of `JobDetails` ?

Comment: @GertArnold I have primary key as a cluster of 'JobID' and 'JobSeq"

Comment: In the database, *and* defined as such in the EF class model?

Comment: @GertArnold After updating entity model code is working fine

Comment: Hi @GertArnold, can you put your suggestions as an answer.Hope it'll help lot of devs in the future.

Comment: hope you can accept this solution no ? http://stackoverflow.com/a/40180230/1077309 here how to do that : http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 2):

Repetitive identical objects are nearly always a tell-tale of primary key inaccuracies: the PK that EF knows about does not uniquely identify the actual records in the database. This frequently happens when views are mapped to EF models, because a view is just a stored query that maybe doesn't even bother about unique identification.

In your case you changed the single primary key to a composite key, without EF knowing it, or you only told EF that `JobID` was the primary key.

When EF materializes an entity object it creates an `EntityKey` for it that has a reference to the entity. These `EntityKey` *have* to be unique, otherwise the change tracker crashes. So when there are two entities, identified by `{ 1, 1 }` and `{ 1, 2 }`, while EF only looks at the `1`, EF will use an existing entity key for the second entity. The weird part, I think, is that EF still decides to materialize a second instance matching this entity key. If it wouldn't you'd have seen only one `JobDetails` record which might have better directed your suspicions to the right spot.